# How to stop iMessage from coming to Macbook

Tags: iphone

I have a school computer and my school has been known to be nosey. I don't want them reading my messages but iCloud and iMessage are both blocked so I can't do anything through there. Ive already tried changing the send &I receive section in my iPhone, please help

Comment: What does _I've already tried changing the send & receive section in my iPhone_ mean? Did you disable or remove the email address that is being used on your MacBook for iCloud? Also, can you clarify what version of macOS is installed on the MacBook? And can you access System Preferences on your MacBook or not?

Comment: On my phone I made it so it uses my phone number and not my email address. I disabled it but it works anyway. The macOS version is OS X El Capitan 10.11.5, I can access system preferences but only certain tabs.

Answer (score 1):

The only way for your iMessages to also be delivered to your MacBook is if they've been set up that way with the same Apple ID / iCloud account you've set up on your iPhone.

It's not 100% clear what you've actually done in the *Send & Receive* settings on your iPhone, but just to be clear:

1. On your iPhone, go to Settings
2. Swipe up and tap on Messages
3. Now tap on Send & Receive
4. Under the *You can be reached by iMessage at* heading, make sure that the iCloud email address used on the MacBook is **not** enabled.

This should rectify the issue. Let me know how you go.